# How to get all of li when click on one li?

Tags: jquery

I want to when clicked on Li another Li that are in same ul show me on ul width class "container-bar".

```
<ul>
     <li class="item-menu dropdown">

          <ul class="sub-menu">`
              <li class="sub-item-menu"><a href="/Properteis      /PropertiesIndex"><span class="fa fa-file-text"></span>one-o</a></li>
              <li class="sub-item-menu"><a href="/Properteis/PropertiesUnit"><span class="fa fa-pie-chart"></span>one-t</a></li>
              <li class="sub-item-menu"><a href="/Properteis/PropertyCategories"><span class="fa fa-object-group"></span>one-th</a></li>                  
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can simply get all li by using:

    var li = $('li');

But why you want it like?

Comment: for example : when i clicked on second li , it shoud showed in div that has class container-bar with all of three li

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a *li*, you can get the parent's children.

See [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), see [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), and [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```html
<script>
  //On DOMContentLoaded
  $(function() {
      //On click on a <li>
      $('li').on('click', function() {
          //Get every li in the parent ul
          var allLi = $(this).parent().children("li");
      });  
  });
</script>
```